# Organize data based on a weird column distribution in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there an elegant way of segment data in a dataframe in which the first row includes the name of the data owner, and the second row includes headers, with all the data organized below?

I have this:

```
0   n_1 NaN NaN NaN NaN n_2 NaN NaN NaN NaN ... n_3 NaN NaN NaN NaN n_4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  ... V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
2   45  43  30  32  NaN 45  52  47  47  NaN ... 45  57  51  50  NaN 45  51  47  50  NaN
3   50  53  38  38  NaN 50  55  50  41  NaN ... 50  51  48  49  NaN 50  53  52  52  1
4   50  54  37  41  NaN 50  53  49  49  1   ... 50  54  50  47  NaN 50  54  48  41  1
5   50  51  40  39  NaN 50  53  50  48  NaN ... 50  53  50  49  NaN 50  51  49  50  NaN
6   50  53  47  50  NaN 50  50  47  35  NaN ... 50  55  44  34  NaN 50  50  47  47  NaN
7   50  51  47  45  NaN 50  52  48  48  1   ... 50  51  48  46  NaN 50  51  47  50  NaN
8   50  52  50  50  NaN 50  50  47  50  NaN ... 50  51  47  48  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 50  54  51  53  NaN ... 50  52  48  51  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I need to order that so that I can analyze it in something like:

```
0   Own V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  
1   n_1 45  43  30  32  NaN 
2   n_1 50  53  38  38  NaN 
3   n_1 50  54  37  41  NaN 
4   n_1 50  51  40  39  NaN 
5   n_1 50  53  47  50  NaN 
6   n_1 50  51  47  45  NaN 
7   n_1 50  52  50  50  NaN 
8   n_2 45  52  47  47  NaN 
9   n_2 50  55  50  41  NaN 
10  n_2 50  53  49  49  1   
11  n_2 50  53  50  48  NaN 
12  n_2 50  50  47  35  NaN 
13  n_2 50  52  48  48  1   
14  n_2 50  50  47  50  NaN 
15  n_2 50  54  51  53  NaN 
16  n_3 45  57  51  50  NaN 
17  n_3 50  51  48  49  NaN 
18  n_3 50  54  50  47  NaN 
19  n_3 50  53  50  49  NaN 
20  n_3 50  55  44  34  NaN 
21  n_3 50  51  48  46  NaN 
22  n_3 50  51  47  48  NaN 
23  n_3 50  52  48  51  NaN
24  n_4 45  51  47  50  NaN
25  n_4 50  53  52  52  1
26  n_4 50  54  48  41  1
27  n_4 50  51  49  50  NaN
28  n_4 50  50  47  47  NaN
29  n_4 50  50  51  47  NaN
```

I though about making different dataframes, but that would be a waste of resources. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I’d go back to the source and ask they sort their data out.

Comment: @S3DEV it looks like a valid dataset to me, just a standard multi index that was read in in-correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use a multi index.

from source this should work. The operative argument here is `headers` in which you tell the `read_csv` function what arguments are required for read.

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv',headers=[0,1])
df = df.stack(0).reset_index(1).rename(columns={0 : 'own'})

print(df)

1  own  V1  V2  V3  V4   V5
2  n_1  45  43  30  32  NaN
2  n_2  45  52  47  47  NaN
2  n_3  45  57  51  50  NaN
2  n_4  45  51  47  50  NaN
3  n_1  50  53  38  38  NaN
3  n_2  50  55  50  41  NaN
3  n_3  50  51  48  49  NaN
3  n_4  50  53  52  52    1
4  n_1  50  54  37  41  NaN
4  n_2  50  53  49  49    1
4  n_3  50  54  50  47  NaN
4  n_4  50  54  48  41    1
5  n_1  50  51  40  39  NaN
5  n_2  50  53  50  48  NaN
5  n_3  50  53  50  49  NaN
5  n_4  50  51  49  50  NaN
6  n_1  50  53  47  50  NaN
6  n_2  50  50  47  35  NaN
6  n_3  50  55  44  34  NaN
6  n_4  50  50  47  47  NaN
7  n_1  50  51  47  45  NaN
7  n_2  50  52  48  48    1
7  n_3  50  51  48  46  NaN
7  n_4  50  51  47  50  NaN
8  n_1  50  52  50  50  NaN
8  n_2  50  50  47  50  NaN
8  n_3  50  51  47  48  NaN
9  n_2  50  54  51  53  NaN
9  n_3  50  52  48  51  NaN
```

--

If your `MultiIndex` comes out malformed due to the source data we can fudge it by manually fixing it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv',headers=None)

s = df.iloc[:2].T.replace('NaN',np.nan).ffill() # you may need to be smart with your replace here. 
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s)

df1 = df.stack(0).reset_index(1).rename(columns={0 : 'own'}).iloc[2:]
```

which will yield the same as the above.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an intuitive way using `pandas.DataFrame` and a for loop. There's maybe a better way to do this (that is more elegent and less resource extensive) so I am curious to see other solutions to this problem.

In the meantime, here is mine.

My solution is separated in two steps. The first is to fill the NA values in the first row with the previous one. The Second is to use a for loop an concatenate the dataframes to form the new one.

To test this example, I have made this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["n_1", np.nan, np.nan, "n_2", np.nan, np.nan, "n_3", np.nan, np.nan],
                  ["V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3"],
                  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

I filled the NA in the first row using

```
df.iloc[0, :] = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[0, :]
```

And finally I used the for loop through every group to concatenate every segment of the dataframe correctly.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["grp", "V1", "V2", "V3"]) # the new df

all_groups = np.unique(df.iloc[0, :]) # groups = "n_1", "n_2", ...
for grp in all_groups:
    group_df = df.loc[:, df.iloc[0, :] == grp] # get the part of the df corresponding to groupe `grp`
    group_df = group_df.iloc[1:,:] # remove the first row
    group_df.columns = group_df.iloc[0,:] # set the column as ["V1", "V2", "V3"]
    group_df["grp"] = grp # create new column "grp" with the group name
    group_df = group_df.iloc[1:,:] # remove the row containing ["V1", "V2", "V3"]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, group_df], axis=0) # concatenate the group_df to the new_df
```

And then the final df looks like:

```
    grp     V1  V2  V3
1   n_1     1   1   1
2   n_1     1   1   1
3   n_2     2   2   2
4   n_2     2   2   2
5   n_3     3   3   3
6   n_3     3   3   3
```